# Auto include save date in filename?

Tags: microsoft-word, date, filenames

Can I set an option to automatically include the save date in an MSWord filename?

Comment: As part of the text, or in the metadata?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with MS Word a lot over the years, and I'm quite sure there's no option that does anything like that. You *could* write a VBA macro or program some .NET automation so you could have a special button that saves the current file under a automatically generated file name. But unless it's feature that would save you a lot of work, it's not worth the trouble.